# typoscript call php function and print result

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I want to call a simple PHP script with typoscript to print the results of it.

I tried this,

```
lib.doSomething = USER                                                      
lib.doSomething {
       userFunc = fileadmin/pcoShowBlog.inc.php
}

page.20.marks.kumulierterInhalt  < lib.doSomething
```

What is wrong in this case?

Update

also tried this:

```
lib.obj = USER
lib.obj.includeLibs = fileadmin/pcoShowBlog.inc.php
lib.obj.userFunc = Blog->showBlog

page.20.marks.kumulierterInhalt  < lib.obj
```

and this:

```
page.10 = USER_INT
page.10 {
  userFunc = In2code\MyUserFuncs\Blog->showBlog
}

page.20.marks.kumulierterInhalt = page.10.userFunc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You should not have any PHP files in fileadmin (security)!**

Use an own extension and give the class and method name to the userFunc.

`lib.doSomething.userFunc = Vendor\ExtensionName\UserFunc\ShowBlog->methodName`

Answer (score 0):

**I work on TYPO3 10.4**

I wanted to run function from my controller before frontend login, so I created my plugin and put it above felogin plugin.

For call function from my controller I use typoscipt like this:

```
lib.doSomething = USER
lib.doSomething {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = extName
  vendorName = vendor
  pluginName = plugin
}
```

In template I just put

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.doSomething"/>
```

Problem can appears with more then one function in controller, because *switchableControllerActions* is deprecated, I suggest this solution: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.3/Deprecation-89463-SwitchableControllerActions.html